# Combining 2 MySQL Queries from Different Databases

Tags: mysql

I've been trying my hand at this and I just keep getting an error or a query that hangs. Basically I have two database queries (one from each database) and I need to combine the results of the first into the second but also use the ID of the second query in the first...confusing!

The first is a simple query. Getting the number of topics approved and set it as "commentnumber". As you can see in the **WHERE** clause: It needs to use **a.ID** which would be from the **second query**.

**Database 1**

```
(SELECT (t.topic_posts_approved - 1) 
    FROM forum.bb_topics t, forum.bb_xpost xp
    WHERE xp.wp_id = a.ID
    AND t.topic_id = xp.topic_id) as 'commentnumber'
```

This is a query I've created to get 3 wordpress posts and sort them by a "weight". If I remove "**commentnumber**" (from the first query) it'll obviously work.

**Database 2**

```
SELECT a.post_author, a.id, b.pageviews, a.post_title, a.guid, c.meta_value,  (b.pageviews * (c.meta_value + (commentnumber * 1.25))) AS 'weight'
FROM wordpress.wp_posts a, wordpress.wp_poppodyd b, wordpress.wp_postmeta c 
WHERE a.ID = b.postid and (a.ID = c.post_id)
AND c.meta_key = 'thumbs_up' 
AND (b.day >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
GROUP BY a.post_author
ORDER BY weight DESC
LIMIT 3
```

I've tried inner joining them but I either don't know what I'm doing or the query is just too much because a few variations I've tried just hangs until killed.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Prefix databasename to the table/column. eg: dbname.tablename.columnname

Comment: You might need to use the database name before the tables in your queries, since they come from different databases.
Like, test.wp_posts

Comment: Sorry folks, I pre-fixed the database names before them in the FROM clause. Would an inner join still be recommended?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out after sitting down for a couple of more hours with it.

As people have said, using the ***database.table.column name*** is the key.

Here is my end result in one query:

```
SELECT a.post_author, a.id, b.pageviews, a.post_title, a.guid, c.meta_value, t.topic_posts_approved, (b.pageviews * (c.meta_value + (t.topic_posts_approved * 1.25))) AS 'weight'
FROM wordpressdb.wp_posts a, wordpressdb.wp_poppodyd b, wordpressdb.wp_postmeta c, forumdb.bb_topics t, forumdb.bb_xpost xp
WHERE a.ID = b.postid and (a.ID = c.post_id) and (a.ID = xp.wp_id) and (t.topic_id = xp.topic_id)
AND c.meta_key = 'thumbs_up' 
AND (b.day >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
GROUP BY a.post_author
ORDER BY weight DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a new table and use both the database, select the columns that what you need and insert it to the new table then you can easily able to read that table.

Comment: The issue is that the data being pulled from both databases is constantly being updated so every result could end up being different. I'm guessing this would require me to have to continually export the columns into the new table?

Comment: you can try to make it as a single db (i.e) create two new tables and store it in any one db, later you can use joins to select you query. even though when page loads again it will show you fully and it wont duplicate data.